# Can I pass data of Datatable to some method on button click function

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I used dataTable in my project and I added a custom column to it with edit and delete button. I am able to pass individual fields to function. Is it possible to pass while object as argument to function?

Below is my dataTable code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var table1;
    $(function(){

        table1 = $('#simpletable').DataTable({
        processing  :true,
        serverSide  :true,
        //table: '#simpletable',
        ajax    :"{{route('shippingPreference.create')}}",
        columns   :[

        // { data: "id" },
        { data: "channel_name" },
        { data: "process_type" },
        { data: "method_name" },
        { data: "market_place_shipping_method_name" },
        {
            sortable: false,
            "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
              console.log(full);
              var actionhtml='<button data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" id="'+full.id+'" title="Remove" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" >' +
                    '<i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Edit"  class="btn btn-info btn-xs" onclick="callMe('+full+')">'+
                    '<i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
                return actionhtml;
            }
        }
    ],
    } );
 });
```

Comment: What happens when you run the above code?

Comment: it give error, undefined..

Comment: I think the problem is that you're effectively trying to print out the `full` object as part of the `<a>` tag, so you may have to use `JSON.stringify(full)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @markpsmith told, you have to use `JSON.stringify(full)` and use single quote instead of double quote in your code:

```
var actionhtml='<button data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" id="'+full.id+'" title="Remove" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" >' +
                    '<i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Edit"  class="btn btn-info btn-xs" onclick=\'callMe('+JSON.stringify(full)+')\'>'+
                    '<i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
```